# Find the product $(1-a_1)(1-a_2)(1-a_3)(1-a_4)(1-a_5)(1-a_6)$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $1,$ $a_i$ for $1 \leq i \leq 6$ be the different roots of $x^7-1$.
Then find the product:
$(1-a_1)(1-a_2)(1-a_3)(1-a_4)(1-a_5)(1-a_6)$

I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**.  Factorising,
$$x^7-1=(x-1)(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_6)\ .$$
Dividing by $x-1$ gives
$$x^6+x^5+\cdots+1=(x-a_1)\cdots(x-a_6)\ .$$
I'm sure you can finish the problem from here.

Comment: Yes, this was cool.

Answer (score 6):

$$x^7-1=\prod_{i=1}^7 (x-a_i)$$ with $a_7=1$. So the product is $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^7-1}{x-1}=7$$

Comment: I didn't follow.

Comment: Did you understand the first step, i.e. writing $x^7-1$ in the product form?

Comment: Yes. But I don't understand the seco step

Comment: The product you want to evaluate can be obtained by putting $x=1$ in the second step, because $(x^7-1)/(x-1)=(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)(x-a_5)(x-a_6)$. Is it okay now?

Comment: Yes I follow now..

Answer (score 1):

We have $$(x-1)(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)(x-a_5)(x-a_6)=(x-1)(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+x^{4}+x^{5}+x^{6}).$$ Hence we must have $$(x-a_1)(x-a_2)(x-a_3)(x-a_4)(x-a_5)(x-a_6)=1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+x^{4}+x^{5}+x^{6}.$$ This is because I am dividing the same monomial $x-1$ from both sides. Hence we have $$\prod_{i=1}^{6}(1-a_i)=7.$$